# Spherical Coordinates Help equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $S$ be the solid bounded above by the upper half of the cone $z^2=x^2+y^2$ and below by the paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$

a) Write equations in spherical coordinates for the cone and paraboloid listed above.
b) Express the integral $$\int \int \int_S \frac{x}{1-y}dV$$ in spherical coordinates

I have alot of trouble with spherical coordinates but for part a) I think I got
$$\int^{1}_0 \int^{2 \pi}_0 \int_{\pi /4}^{\pi / 2} d\phi d\theta d \rho$$

Answer (score 1):

The upper half of $z^2 = x^2+y^2$, in spherical coordinates, is:
$$
\rho^2 \cos^2\phi = \rho^2 \sin^2\phi\cos^2 \theta+\rho^2 \sin^2\phi \sin^2 \theta\quad \Rightarrow\quad \phi = \frac{\pi}{4}
$$
The paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$, in spherical coordinates, is:
\begin{align}
&\rho \cos\phi = \rho^2 \sin^2\phi\cos^2 \theta+\rho^2 \sin^2\phi \sin^2 \theta \\ &\Rightarrow\quad \rho \cos\phi = \rho^2 \sin^2\phi 
\\ &\Rightarrow\quad \rho = \frac{\cos\phi}{\sin^2\phi}
\end{align}
Therefore, you can express $S$ as follows:
$$
\{(\rho,\theta,\phi)\mid 0\le \theta \le 2 \pi,\; \pi /4 \le \phi \le \pi/2, 0\le \rho \le \frac{\cos\phi}{\sin^2\phi} \}
$$
It follows that
$$
\iiint_S \frac{x}{1-y} \; dV = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\frac{\cos\phi}{\sin^2\phi}} \frac{\rho \sin \phi \cos \theta}{1-\rho \sin \phi \sin \theta}\;\rho^2 \sin \phi \; d\rho d \phi d \theta
$$